# How to decompile ex4 file to mq4

Tags: mql4, algorithmic-trading, mql5, forex

How can someone decompile ex4 file to mq4 file. I want to view the source code. Or rather how can you change the name of a expert adviso

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of decompilers out there that can produce some source code that might run using MT4. One of them is IDA Pro another NSA Ghidra, you just need to make sense in cryptography and binary decompilation. Another option is to look for more complex decompilers that decompile some code on processor level. You are going to get some binary code that is almost impossible to read for humans or decrypt using any online decryption tool. You should be resilient and have a compiled ex4 containing all the functions of MQL4. After matching the binaries you might be able to reconstruct the source code into semi-readable MQL4 code. You should note that after decompilation you will get an obfuscated code, which means that even after decompiling you can't get into changing things inside of the EA, Indicator or Script of some kind. This means that after decompilation you should also deobfuscate the code to understand all underlying algorithms inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Now that ex4 are compiled programs and not byte code, it is much more difficult to decompile.

Of course, the main purpose of delivering an EX4 file and not the source is the source is closed and the developer doesn't want to disclose it. EX4 to MQ4 converters are used to circumvent this "protection".

Answer (score 1):

To gain access to the source code of EX4 file, you should first contact its developer. Most EAs for MetaTrader are distributed without source code.

Decompilation of EX4 file to get the source code *for educational purposes* is possible in principle. However, this is a very time consuming process.

Also, according to MetaTrader developers, this is not legal in most countries.